# Where's my gold badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just reached 10000 views for a question.

I don't seem to have received a gold badge.

Where is my gold badge?

Answer (score 1):

It is not rewarded instantly. Give the system some time to work it out ;)

[Here is the full feathered post from main Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) regarding the magic of badges. Specifically see this part:

> In some cases badges gained or lost may not show up immediately, but
>   it will instead be awarded the next time the system recalculates
>   badges, which occurs periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Your Badge have been awarded, and can be seen on the following link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=5165